# Decode the number to get a color!

Tags: mathematics, cipher

These numbers in some way represents 4 commonly used colors: **25536, 187669382, 3043469, 11599**
Can you decode it?

Include the answer and your thought process to get the check mark.

Let me know if you need more hints.

Hint 1:

> It requires 3 steps to decode

Comment: To clarify, each number in bold represents one of the 4 colors? Assuming, but the title/starting with "this number" makes me want to be sure before diving down any rabbit holes.

Comment: Correct, sorry I meant these, i will fix. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: All good, sometimes the devil is in the details though, I've wasted a lot of time going down the wrong path lol

Comment: @TCooper Lol Should I give another hint?

Comment: I'd wait a day or so for another hint, it's a global community, gives everyone a crack at it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see "3 steps to decode"

> transfer numbers to base-26 / or A-Z as numbers.
>  For example RED = $26^2*17 + 26^1*4 + 26^0*3 = 11599 $

so

> 25536 -> BLUE
>  187669382 -> PURPLE
>  3043469 -> GREEN
>  11599 -> RED

Well

> This system only have problem with words that starts with "A", because it represents zero.

Comment: You got it. You kind of merged the 2nd and 3rd steps. Second was to take the base 26 digits and add 1. Third was to convert using the A=1, B=2, C=3 ... code. Also it wouldn't be a problem with a's.

Comment: @Ankit For A=1,Z=26 you would need Base27, since in Base26 there would be A0=Z. So A=0, Z=25 is just normal Base26. There is problem with A=0, how would you in your code write just "AA"…